# ANT does not load my environment variables correctly

Tags: ant, environment-variables, backslash

I have a problem with an ant script so I added some echos to finde the source of the error. I guesed that it might be the environemt variable for my Android SDK so i added

```
<echo level="info">     sdk.dir= ${sdk.dir} </echo>
```

and it prints

```
[echo]      sdk.dir= c:UsersSpongeDocumentsMy DropboxAndroid SDK
```

I set the environment variable like this (i user Win7):

```
Name: ANDROID_HOME
Value: C:\Users\Sponge\Documents\My Dropbox\Android SDK
```

I dont have very much experience with ANT so maybe its just the behaviour of the echo command that the backslashes are removed and the path is correct, or is this the problem why the script can't find the resource anttasks.properties for example, which is in the SDK folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a properties file, backslashes must be escaped (using another backslash):

```
Name: ANDROID_HOME
Value: C:\\Users\\Sponge\\Documents\\My Dropbox\\Android SDK
```

I wouldn't bother with backslashes, and use clashes instead, which ant (and Java in general) supports just fine, even on Windows:

```
Name: ANDROID_HOME
Value: C:/Users/Sponge/Documents/My Dropbox/Android SDK
```